# Give names to images based on the date

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, layer-name

I have a code that calculates NDVI , add the layer and export it.

I have another piece of code that I thought that will change the name of each image I have to the date, but for some reason it doesn do it. I t also suppoose to add the raster to the layer but that doesn't happen.

this is my code:

```
//STEP 1:NDVI

/**
 * Function to mask clouds using the Sentinel-2 QA band
 * @param {ee.Image} image Sentinel-2 image
 * @return {ee.Image} cloud masked Sentinel-2 image
 */
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000)
  .copyProperties(image, ['system:time_start']);
}

// Map the function over one year of data and take the median.
// Load Sentinel-2 TOA reflectance data.
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
                  .filterDate('2019-01-01', '2019-11-12')
                  // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20))
                  .select('B2','B3','B4','B8','QA60')
                  .filterBounds(geometry)
                  .map(maskS2clouds);

var clippedCol=dataset.map(function(im){ 
   return im.clip(geometry);
});

// Get the number of images.
var count = dataset.size();
print('Count: ',count);
// print(clippedCol);//here I get the error messege "collection query aborted after accumulation over 5000 elements
// print(dataset,'dataset');//the same error here

//function to calculate NDVI
var addNDVI = function(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4'])
  .rename('NDVI')
  .copyProperties(image,['system:time_start']);
  return image.addBands(ndvi);

};

//NDVI to the clipped image collection
var withNDVI = clippedCol.map(addNDVI).select('NDVI');


var NDVIcolor = {
  min: 0,
  max:1,
  palette: ['FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718', '74A901',
    '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201', '004C00', '023B01',
    '012E01', '011D01', '011301'],
};

//Filter according to number of pixels

var ndviWithCount = withNDVI.map(function(image){
  var countpixels = ee.Number(image.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
  geometry: geometry,
  crs: 'EPSG:4326',
  scale: 20,
  }).get('NDVI'));

  return image.set('count', countpixels);
});

print(ndviWithCount, 'ndviWithCount');

var max = ndviWithCount.reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.max(),  ["count"]);
print('Number of pixels max:',max.get('max'));


//filter between a range
var filterNDVI = ndviWithCount.filter(ee.Filter.rangeContains(
          'count', 889906, 889906));
print('Filtered NDVI:', filterNDVI);

// Get the number of filltered images.
var count_filter = filterNDVI.size();


//List NDVI
var listNDVI=filterNDVI.toList(count_filter);
    for (var i=0;i<count_filter;i++){
         var image1=ee.Image(listNDVI.get(i));
         var date = image1.date().format('yyyy-MM-dd').getInfo();
         var name_i= 'NDVI_'+i.toString()+'_'+date;
         print(name_i);
    // Export NDVI 
      Map.addLayer(image, NDVIcolor, name_i);
         Export.image.toDrive({ 
               image: image,
               description: name_i,
               fileNamePrefix: name_i,
               scale: 20,
               region:geometry,
               crs : 'EPSG:4326'
               });
    }

print(listNDVI);
```

My end goal:
1. To give each raster layer name that will actually be the date of the image 
2. To add all of those images using "Map.addLaeyer" (now they don't appear).

**EDIT:** I have tried to use Daniel's code but it got error message "invalid time value", this is how I used it:

```
var clippedCol=dataset.map(function(im){ 
   return im.clip(geometry);
});

// Get the number of images.
var count = dataset.size();
print('Count: ',count);
// print(clippedCol);//here I get the error messege "collection query aborted after accumulation over 5000 elements
// print(dataset,'dataset');//the same error here



//function to calculate NDVI
var addNDVI = function(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4'])
  .rename('NDVI')
  .copyProperties(image,['system:time_start']);
  return image.addBands(ndvi);

};

//NDVI to the clipped image collection
var withNDVI = clippedCol.map(addNDVI).select('NDVI');


var NDVIcolor = {
  min: 0,
  max:1,
  palette: ['FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718', '74A901',
    '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201', '004C00', '023B01',
    '012E01', '011D01', '011301'],
};

//Filter according to number of pixels

var ndviWithCount = withNDVI.map(function(image){
  var countpixels = ee.Number(image.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
  geometry: geometry,
  crs: 'EPSG:4326',
  scale: 20,
  }).get('NDVI'));

  return image.set('count', countpixels);
});

print(ndviWithCount, 'ndviWithCount');

var max = ndviWithCount.reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.max(),  ["count"]);
print('Number of pixels max:',max.get('max'));
var number_max=max.get('max');

//filter between a range
var filterNDVI = ndviWithCount.filter(ee.Filter.rangeContains(
          'count', number_max, number_max));
print('Filtered NDVI:', filterNDVI);

//HERE I STARTED  TO USE DANIEL'S CODE
//THE ADDLAYER PART IS ON THE END OF THIS CODE
var timeStartsNDVI =filterNDVI
  .distinct('system:time_start')
  .aggregate_array('system:time_start');

timeStartsNDVI.evaluate(function (timeStarts, error) {
  if (error) print('Error: ' + error);
  timeStarts.forEach(function (timeStart) {
    var image = filterNDVI
      .filterMetadata('system:time_start', 'equals', timeStart)
      .first();
    // Map.addLayer(
    //   image, 
    //   {bands: 'B4,B3,B2', min: 0, max: 3000}, 
    //   new Date(timeStart).toISOString()
    // )
  }); 
});



var listOfImages =(filterNDVI.toList(filterNDVI.size()));

// var NumberOfImages=listOfImages.size();

// var listOfNumbers = ee.List.sequence(0,NumberOfImages.subtract(1));
// listOfNumbers = listOfNumbers.map(function(n) {
//   return ee.Number(n).add(1);
// });
// print(typeof(listOfNumbers));


var listOfNumbers = [5];



for (var i in listOfNumbers) {
  var image = ee.Image(listOfImages.get(listOfNumbers[i]));
  var toexport=image.visualize(NDVIcolor).addBands(image);


  //do what ever you need with image
  Map.addLayer(image, NDVIcolor, new Date(timeStartsNDVI).toISOString());
  // Export.image.toDrive({
  // image: toexport.toFloat(),
  // description: i,
  // scale:20,
  // crs:'EPSG:4326',
  // maxPixels:1310361348,
  // region:geometry.geometry().bounds()


// });


}
Map.centerObject(geometry);
```

Comment: Probably you just need to make your `count_filter` client-side using e.g. `getInfo()`. Sharing a link of your code would include your geometry variable, which enables others to run your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like the below. Chances are your will run into trouble if you add too many images at the same time though.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/842e3f62198b1a5cf72b45fb91bd7574

```
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
  .filterDate('2018-06-01', '2018-07-01')
  .filterBounds(Map.getBounds(true))

var timeStarts = collection
  .distinct('system:time_start')
  .aggregate_array('system:time_start')

timeStarts.evaluate(function (timeStarts, error) {
  if (error) print('Error: ' + error)
  timeStarts.forEach(function (timeStart) {
    var image = collection
      .filterMetadata('system:time_start', 'equals', timeStart)
      .first()
    Map.addLayer(
      image, 
      {bands: 'B4,B3,B2', min: 0, max: 3000}, 
      new Date(timeStart).toISOString()
    )
  }) 
})
```

**UPDATE**

Please, always include a link to a working EE script, instead of just sharing snippets of code. It makes it easier to help you.

To solve your problem, you have to do some client-side looping. It's easy to get wrong (Read up on this: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/client_server#looping). The evaluate() function moves from the server-side world to the client-side. The client-side code should stay there. Below, I just limited the number of images you display/export and moved your code into the evaluate() block.

```
var timeStartsNDVI =filterNDVI
  .distinct('system:time_start')
  .limit(5) // Take the first 5 images
  .aggregate_array('system:time_start');

timeStartsNDVI.evaluate(function (timeStarts, error) {
  if (error) print('Error: ' + error);
  try {
    timeStarts.forEach(function (timeStart, i) {
      var image = filterNDVI
        .filterMetadata('system:time_start', 'equals', timeStart)
        .first();
      var toexport=image.visualize(NDVIcolor).addBands(image);      
      Map.addLayer(image, NDVIcolor, new Date(timeStart).toISOString());
      Export.image.toDrive({
        image: toexport.toFloat(),
        description: 'NDVI' + i,
        scale:20,
        crs:'EPSG:4326',
        maxPixels:1310361348,
         // You didn't include the geometry in the script you shared.
         // I assumed it was an ee.Geometry() - if so, geometry.geometry().bounds() wouldn't work
        // region:geometry.geometry().bounds()
        region:geometry.bounds() 
      });
    }); 
  } catch(e) {
    print('Error: ' + e);
  }
});
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/597da00da68a3074d52e6b0bccc0f202

Comment: I have tried this , a bit different, you can see on the iriginal message. it  almost worked, but I got error "invalid time value"